# Unwanted validation rule being applied on password reset

Tags: laravel, validation, forgot-password, broker, validationrules

I'm trying to use the password reset ability of Laravel's authentication. After running **make:auth** command, inside my ResetPasswordController, I have overridden **rules** function of Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords trait as the following:

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:4',    
    ];
}
```

So, I am trying to change the minimum length value to 4. But when I try to reset my password, a rule of minimum of 8 characters is still being applied instead of 4. 
Here is the **reset** function of laravel in the same file:

```php
public function reset(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

    // Here we will attempt to reset the user's password. If it is successful we
    // will update the password on an actual user model and persist it to the
    // database. Otherwise we will parse the error and return the response.
    $response = $this->broker()->reset(
        $this->credentials($request), function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        }
    );

    // If the password was successfully reset, we will redirect the user back to
    // the application's home authenticated view. If there is an error we can
    // redirect them back to where they came from with their error message.
    return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
}
```

And the **$response** being returned is Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password::INVALID_PASSWORD. I don't understand where this rule is coming from.
Actually the validation behavior is like this: When I enter less than 4 characters, my own rule is applied (correctly). However, entering 4 to less than 8 characters is also an error by some other rule.

Comment: Did you change the code in the actual trait or in the controller?

Comment: @Rwd I didn't change the trait. I added new rules function in the controller to override it.

Comment: What version of  Laravel are you using?

Comment: @Rwd version 5.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you're getting the error back is because the `PasswordBroker` expects a password with a minimum length of 8 characters so even though your form validation is passing, the validation in the `PasswordBroker` isn't.

One way to get around this would be to override the `broker()` method in your `ResetPasswordController` and pass your own validator to it:

```
public function broker()
{
    $broker = Password::broker();

    $broker->validator(function ($credentials) {
        return $credentials['password'] === $credentials['password_confirmation'];
    });

    return $broker;
}
```

The above is essentially the same as what's going on in the `PasswordBroker` itself, just without the string length check as well.

Don't forget to import the `Password` facade into your controller:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
```

---

This isn't essential, but for good measure I would then suggest updating the `password` error message in your `resources/lang/en/passwords.php` file as well.