# How to override this text - the password must be at least 8 characters

Tags: laravel

How can i override this text on laravel, when validation fails
I've searching this text all over project but didn't find also

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007905/custom-laravel-validation-messages

Comment: Welcome to SO ... i bet if you searched for "must be at least" you will find them in the validation lang file.

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/2c69ec987e2dca71008684fc80bbe56c55427dc3/resources/lang/en/validation.php#L87

Comment: This is a form validation error right? If so why not just tweak the rule at where the validation is handled from `min:8` to whatever, or remove it entirely?

Comment: This might answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57253476/unwanted-validation-rule-being-applied-on-password-reset/57254666#57254666

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `min:8` rule for the password field, we can create a custom message.

```
e.g: $rules = [
                 'password' => 'min:8|required'
               ];
     $messages = [
                   'password.min' => 'your custom message',
                   'password.required' => 'your custom message'
                  ];
     $isValid = Validator::make($requestInputs, $rules, $messages);
```